# Getting Started with Zend

Tags: apache2, zend

I have a Zend Framework installed on my pc and when I add some actions in            Index Controller I get a 404 ERROR, but if I write some actions on another controller let's say TestController the file will be sent to browser.
My apache2.conf configuration is :

```
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the 

# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy all
```

My configuration for  etc/apache2/sites-available/default is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My configuration for /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zendexample.local is:
      
         DocumentRoot "/var/www/ZendExample/public"
         ServerName ZendExample.local

```
    # This should be omitted in the production environment
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "/var/www/ZendExample/public">
      Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Same code for etc/apache2/sites-available/zendexample.local
At comand sudo a2enmod rewrite the answer is:
     Module rewrite already enabled
I give restart and reload commands to apache server.

In the end of post I repeat 404 ERROR appears only on IndexController actions(root path) if I put the same code in other controller(using same model) and implicit create a new folder (test)in scripts everytihing seems go well.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, just install Ubuntu 13.04, previous OS Fedora 19 all works fine, bu this problem! I see that you post this 3 month ago, did you have any solution now?

// To addmins, sory.

I have some solution,
OS 13.04 have apache 2.2
last version of xampp have apache 2.4

I install xampp and /index WORK!,
I sink the problem is in apache configs, but with I don't now,
for me the best solution is to use xampp.